KeyError: 'st.secrets has no key "password"
I want to use streamlit secrets for easy access to my streamlit-app via password. I feel like I did everything as described in the documentation.
Streamlit-Doc
But I keep receiving the following Error-Message
KeyError: 'st.secrets has no key "password". Did you forget to add it to 

secrets.toml or the app settings on Streamlit Cloud?
Any ideas how I can fix this?
I added a file with the secrets in my repo and added the file to my .gitignore file
secret-file
.gitignore
then I added the secrets on my app too.
streamlit-community-cloud
lastly added the code section to my code:
import streamlit as st
import hmac

def check_password():
    """Returns `True` if the user had the correct password."""

    def password_entered():
        """Checks whether a password entered by the user is correct."""
        if hmac.compare_digest(st.session_state["password"], st.secrets["password"]):
            st.session_state["password_correct"] = True
            del st.session_state["password"]  # Don't store the password.
        else:
            st.session_state["password_correct"] = False

    # Return True if the password is validated.
    if st.session_state.get("password_correct", False):
        return True

    # Show input for password.
    st.text_input(
        "Password", type="password", on_change=password_entered, key="password"
    )
    if "password_correct" in st.session_state:
        st.error(" Password incorrect")
    return False


if not check_password():
    st.stop()  # Do not continue if check_password is not True.```


KeyError occurs when you are accessing a key in a Python dictionary object that doesn't exist. So, when accessing secrets using st.secrets, Streamlit will raise a KeyError if the secret key doesn’t exist. Please at what line of the code of the code is this error occurring?  Ensure that your secrets are correctly defined in the root directory file of secrets.toml of your project and make sure your environmental variables on their cloud are well set and match the one you have in your project.

Thanks for your answer so far @Blaisemart The Error occurs in line 9  if hmac.compare_digest(st.session_state["password"], st.secrets["password"]):

Ok, thanks for letting me know. Have you solved it yet? Or does my guideline on how to solve it later help out in getting rid of the error? If not, kindly me know.
